# Database reinitialization in Service

Tags: android

Good day!

I've got a persistent Service (infinite loop inside - can be killed only by OS in the wake of memory). This Service contains SQLiteOpenHelper object and do some operations on SQLite database. SQLiteOpenHelper object initialized in onCreate() of Service. The question is - can Service occur any problems with database after being restored by OS?

Comment: `infinite loop inside` - why?

Comment: Determining time of day to start some process - between 7 and 19 every day

Comment: @ЕвгенийКравцов to determine time in the future you have to use `AlarmManager`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html You should think twice before using `infinite loops`. In almost all cases you don't need it.

Comment: You're right, but it's not me who developed app's architecture - i have to deal with that - and i cant do changes, because architecture is bad and changing affect too much elements.